# Calling a variable in javascript using a button

Tags: javascript, function, variables, button, call

I want to make a function and call that function on the click of a button. There are many guides on the internet to do this but it just didn't work. (I'm a beginner)

```
<script type = "javascript/text">
var name = function()
name = prompt ("Who are you?", "");
alert ("hello" + " " + name);
</script>
```

How do i call "name"?

Comment: type must be `type = "text/javascript"`

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. I recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/. Then read about event handling: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript. Stackoverflow is not the right place to learn the language.

Comment: @FelixKling Not as much as one would think: it just sees an empty statement after `function()`. Curly braces aren't required. Sadly JS terminates statements on the end of a line, otherwise it would have been fine.

Comment: @11684: I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. The braces are not optional for function declarations/expressions (http://es5.github.com/#x13).

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code into this:

```
<script>
     var name = prompt ("Who are you?", "");
    alert ("hello" + " " + name);
</script>
```

This should work. You don't even need a function here.

But if you want to store a function in a variable and then call it, just do:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // function body
}
myFunction(); // calling it!
```

Comment: doesn't work because of `type="javascript/text"` instead of `type="text/javascript"`